# No logro entender porque me da este error ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 6

Tags: java

Estoy obteniendo un Exception in thread "main"

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 6 exactamente en este punto.
>
> at primeraclase.PrimeraClase.main(Asiento 14H PrimeraClase.java:81

Se supone que deberia llegar hasta 60 porque el array es de 6 x 10.

Alguien me da una pista de que puede estar pasando?

```
package primeraclase;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class PrimeraClase {


public static void main(String[] args) {

    //EL CODIGO SIGUIENTE ES PARA CREAR LOS ARRAYS QUE CONTIEIEN LOS ASIENTOS 
    //AQUÍ ESTAN LAS SENTIENCIAS PARA LA PRIMERA CLASE
    String[][] primeraClase = new String [6][5];       
    String filasPrimeraClase = "1";
    String asiento;
    char columnaPrimeraClase = 65;
    String letraColumna = Character.toString(columnaPrimeraClase);
    int limiteYprimeraClase = 5;
    int limiteXprimeraClase = 4;
    int contadorPrimeraClase = 0;
    int xp = 0;
    int yp = 0;
    int xAleatorio = 0;       
    int xVentana = 0;
    int xPasillo = 0;

    //AQUI SE DECLARAN TODAS LAS VARIABLES DE LA CLASE TURISTA

    String[][] claseTurista = new String [6][10];       
    String filasClaseTurista = "1";
    String asientoC;
    int limiteYClaseT = 5;
    int limiteXClaseT = 9;
    int contadorClaseT = 0;
    int xpT = 0;
    int ypT = 0;
    int xAleatorioClaseT = 0;       
    int xVentanaClaseT = 0;
    int xPasilloClaseT = 0;
    char columnaClaseT = 70;
    String letraColumnaT = Character.toString(columnaClaseT);


    //AQUI ESTAN LAS VAARIABLES QUE SE COMPARTEN  EN AMBAS CLASES
    int yAleatorio = 1;
    int yVentana = 0;
    int yPasillo = 2;
    int limiteYPasillo = 3;
    int limiteYAleatorio =  4;
    int limiteYVentana = 5;


    //AQUI SE CONSTRUYE LA PRIMERA CLASE

    while(primeraClase[5][4] == null)

    {
      primeraClase[xp][yp] = "Asiento " + filasPrimeraClase + letraColumna;
        asiento = primeraClase[xp][yp];
        //System.out.println(asiento + "\n");
        yp++;
        //estas lineas nos permiten modificar el valor del contador a la vez que añadirlo a array en forma de String
        contadorPrimeraClase = Integer.parseInt(filasPrimeraClase);
        contadorPrimeraClase++;
        filasPrimeraClase = String.valueOf(contadorPrimeraClase);
        if(yp == limiteYprimeraClase)
            {
                yp = yp - limiteYprimeraClase;
                xp++;
                //ESTA SECCION PERMITE INTERCAMBIAR ENTRE STRING Y CHAR PARA PODER GUARDARLO COMO STRING EN EL ARREGLO
                columnaPrimeraClase = letraColumna.charAt(0);
                columnaPrimeraClase++;
                letraColumna = Character.toString(columnaPrimeraClase);
        }  

    }

    //AQUI ESTA CONSTRUIDA LA CLASE TURISTA Y DESIGNADOS SUS ASIENTOS.

    while(claseTurista[5][9] == null)

    {
        claseTurista[xpT][ypT] = "Asiento " + filasClaseTurista + letraColumnaT;
        asientoC = claseTurista[xpT][ypT];
        System.out.println(asientoC + "\n");
        ypT++;
        //estas lineas nos permiten modificar el valor del contador a la vez que añadirlo a array en forma de String
        contadorClaseT = Integer.parseInt(filasClaseTurista);
        contadorClaseT++;
        filasClaseTurista = String.valueOf(contadorClaseT);
        if(ypT == limiteYClaseT)
            {
                ypT = ypT - limiteYClaseT;
                xpT++;
                //ESTA SECCION PERMITE INTERCAMBIAR ENTRE STRING Y CHAR PARA PODER GUARDARLO COMO STRING EN EL ARREGLO
                columnaClaseT = letraColumnaT.charAt(0);
                columnaClaseT++;
                letraColumnaT = Character.toString(columnaClaseT);
        }  

    }

}

}
```

Comment: Que linea es la 81 e tu código?

Comment: Justo despues de poner el While en la clase turista.

Answer (score 2):

Estas llenando mal tu array, y por eso el error..

hay varias cosas que parecen estar mal.. haciendo debug, y con un seguimiento, podrias haberlas descubierto vos solo. sin embargo mira esto:

```
String[][] primeraClase = new String [6][5];       
int limiteYprimeraClase = 5;
int limiteXprimeraClase = 4;
....
while(primeraClase[5][4] == null)

{
  primeraClase[xp][yp] = "Asiento " + filasPrimeraClase + letraColumna;
    asiento = primeraClase[xp][yp];
    yp++;
    ...
    if(yp == limiteYprimeraClase)
        {
            yp = yp - limiteYprimeraClase;
            xp++;
```

a proposito copie algunas lineas como ejemplo...

fijate que y es tu segundo indice de la matriz.. en este caso va hasta 5.. lo que esta perfecto.. pero x va hasta cuatro... esto anda de casualidad porque nunca te fijaste si el indice x pasaba el limite...

Pero en turista..

```
String[][] claseTurista = new String [6][10];       
int limiteYClaseT = 5;
int limiteXClaseT = 9;
```

tu indice Y, va hasta 5 (cuando deberia ir hasta 9) y tu indice x, va hasta 9 (pero no lo usas nunca)... o sea.. lo escribiste al reves.. o lo pensaste a reves.. o lo que sea, pero esta al reves...

Revisa eso.. con un debug, siguiendo paso a paso que pasaba.. te hubieras dado cuenta. No dejo de recalcarlo, porque es una de las herramientas mas potentes que vas a tener a la hora de entender que pasa en estos casos.